# While having 2 test cases in 2 different classes using same data provider, all values in the super class get reset to null with the 2nd case execution

Tags: java, automation, testng, testng-dataprovider

Currently, I have 3 classes

- Testbase -> which is responsible to configure all global variables needed in the running suite (ex: webdriver config)
- 2 Test Cases each in a separate class extends the test base
- The problem is by running the TestNG.xml all global variables in the testbase get reset to null with the execution of the second TestCase -> exactly when the second test case begins to call its data provider

Here is a sample of the implementation and output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
    <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
        <classes>
        <class
                name="Visual_Automation_Team.Visual_Automation_DevOps.ValidateLinks">
                <methods>
                    <include name="CheckURLValidity" />
                </methods>
            </class>
            <class
                name="Visual_Automation_Team.Visual_Automation_DevOps.ConsoleCheck">
                <methods>
                    <include name="CheckConsoleErrors" />
                </methods>
            </class>            
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

TestBase.Class -> for test suite configuration

```
public class TestBase 
{
    //Those variables get reset to null with the second call of the data provider
    WebDriver driver;
    ConfigurationsController configurationController;
    ResolutionsInfo resolutionInfo;
    SetupEnvironment setupEnvironment;
    String automatedBrowser;
    ValidWebpagesContainer validPagesContainer;
    ExcludedWebpagesContainer excludedPagesContainer;
    IncludedWebpagesContainer includedPagesContainer;
    Webpage basePage;
    
    @BeforeTest
    public void Initialize()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside Initialize");
        configurationController = new ConfigurationsController();
        excludedPagesContainer = new ExcludedWebpagesContainer();
        includedPagesContainer = new IncludedWebpagesContainer(); .....
    }

    //Data provider that get called before executing each testcase we have
    @DataProvider(name="validLinksDP")
    public Object[] ValidLinksDataProvider()
    {   
        System.out.println("inside Data Provider");
        return validPagesContainer.getValidPages().toArray();
    }
}
```

First test case

```
public class ValidateLinks extends TestBase
{
    @Test(priority = 1, enabled = true , dataProvider = "validLinksDP")
    public void CheckURLValidity(Object currentPage) 
    {
        String currentPageUrl = ((Webpage)currentPage).getPageUrl();
        driver.navigate().to(currentPageUrl);
        System.out.println("Inside 'ValidateLinks'"); .....
}
```

second test case

```
public class ConsoleCheck extends TestBase
{   
    
    @Test(priority = 2, enabled = true , dataProvider = "validLinksDP")
    public void CheckConsoleErrors(Object currentPage) 
    {
        String currentPageUrl = ((Webpage)currentPage).getPageUrl();
        driver.navigate().to(currentPageUrl);
        System.out.println("Inside 'CheckConsoleErrors'"); .....
}
```

Variables value while calling data provider with the first test case (working correctly)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iI4ad.png)

Variables value while calling data provider with the second test case (Not Working)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQJzl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Above issue is not related to the DataProvider . You will need to change the testng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" >
    <test  name="Test1">
        <classes>
        <class
                name="Visual_Automation_Team.Visual_Automation_DevOps.ValidateLinks">
                <methods>
                    <include name="CheckURLValidity" />
                </methods>
            </class>           
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->

    <test name="Test2">
        <classes>
       
            <class
                name="Visual_Automation_Team.Visual_Automation_DevOps.ConsoleCheck">
                <methods>
                    <include name="CheckConsoleErrors" />
                </methods>
            </class>            
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

**OR**

Make global variable static . I won't recommend this approach .